# Will indentation of sql queries in Visual COBOL cause issue?

Tags: cobol, microfocus, cobol.net

I am not familiar with COBOL programming language. But as per the requirement I have to work on a COBOL application. I am facing below issue with one SQL query in the application.

Post execution of below code snippet variable var_b should be populated with table column value var_val.

[image]

But after execution the variable var_b value is empty. As the empty value is getting generated we have run a SQL Profiler and observed that join condition is not taking complete column name but remaining query after joining condition is generated properly.

So we re-arranged the above sourced as shown in below image the value is populated properly to var_b because the query taking complete join condition in SQL Profiler.

[image]

I am using below configuration to compile COBOL application.

IDE: Microfocus Visual Cobol for VisualStudio2017

Machine: Windows10 64 bit machine

Compilation Mode: Release mode with X86

Remaining SQL select queries are executed properly only have problem with above query.

So could you please help me to understand the root cause of the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: neither "per COBOL"  nor "per EXEC SQL" standards indentation will have that effect; if this is the case with Visual COBOL's integrated `EXEC SQL` handling then consider opening a bug report with its support team and/or switching to an external preprocessor like GixSQL or ocesql (warning: both don't understand object orientated COBOL which you may use)

Comment: Did the table name go beyond column 72 with your orriginal indentation?

Comment: @piet.t thanks for the reply..before our changes number of characters including indentation is 71 when cursor is placed at the end of line "TestTable2 b" in the first screenshot